# Regex positive lookbehind

Tags: objective-c, regex, regex-lookarounds

Let me apologize first. I've been fighting this SO editor for an hour. Sorry for the lousy formatting.

If I have a regex that matches a given input, then I put that regex into the positive look-behind wrapper, won't it still match the input it matched before?

For example, this input :

```
(NSString*)
```

will register a match with this regex:

```
\(\w*\*\)
```

I have confirmed this on gskinner.com. When I put that regex into the look-behind wrapper like so

```
(?<=\(\w*\*\))....
```

with this as the input:

```
(NSString*)help
```

I do not receive the word help as a return.
This leads me to think I just plainly don't understand the look-behind concept. I watched a tutorial on this concept, but I am at a loss as to why this won't work. If I want to match:

```
(NSString*)
```

and return the next word, how can I go about that?

Comment: Thanks for the help. You got real close. At the end of look-behind wrapper I need four periods to represent the word 'help' and I need a colon before (NSString*). Or just remove the colon from the regex

Comment: Rule of thumb: code blocks (chunks indented with four spaces) format better than inline code (backticks).

Comment: I tried the 4 spaces over and over. I've posted questions before with code, but for some reason, tonite the editor would not work for me

Comment: @jack there has to be a blank line between preceding text and the code block.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a space as the last character of the look behind, but your input has no space before "help". Also, there is no colon character before the input text, yet your look behind requires one.

Remove the space and the colon:

```
(?<=\(\w*\*\))\w+
```

Note that many regex engines disallow variable length look behinds, so a work around is to limit the.number of characters in the word to some large number, eg `99`:

```
 (?<=\(\w{1,99}\*\))\w+
```

Comment: @Bohemian -> I was assisted in my formatting by mu_is_to_short and he left out a few characters. See my comment above. Don't know why I couldn't get the formatting to work myself. I was unaware I could not use variable length look behinds. That bit of info would have saved me a lot of frustration. Thank you for the response and explanation.

Comment: I did some testing and found out what worked, using @Bohemian's suggestion as a starting point. (?<=\(\w{1,99}\*\))\w+ did not work, using NSRegularExpression. (?<=\(\w{1,10}\*\))\w+ did work for words between 1 & 10. What about longer words? Turns out that if I repeat \w{0,10} in the regex, it will allow matching for words in 10 character increments. Switching that to \w{1,11} breaks the look behind.